# TimeValue function in VB6 giving different values

Tags: vb6

I was fixing some legacy code and found an strange behavior.

`DateTime.TimeValue` method for `12:00:00 AM`, some time returns `0` and some time `12:00 AM`.

Comment: Are you printing it as time (ctime) or as a number(cint)?

Comment: USING MsgBox to print directly variant

Comment: Can you show us an example of two dates where the time is reported differently?

Comment: The `TimeValue()` function returns a Variant Date value, not a String.  So hand-wringing over default coercion to a String value is pointless since it can vary by the locale and ShortDate format setting and thus isn't considered reliable anyway.  My guess is you have two machines or two users with different settings.

Comment: This is happening on same machine

Comment: @vinodsahu you need to post your code in, show the places where it returns the different results